# Code equivalent for size property in Interface Builder

Tags: cocoa, nstablecolumn

I'm creating some `NSTableColumn`s dynamically and they appear too tall in the table. In the Interface Builder there is a general setting to adjust the object size (mini, small, regular). Is there any code equivalent for this or should I simply select the font manually?

**Update**

I found that I can get the font with:

```
    NSFont *font = [NSFont systemFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSizeForControlSize:NSMiniControlSize]];
```

However, the row height doesn't match the items' height. Setting the font in code does nothing with the row height. I use `NSTextFieldCell`s and `NSPopUpButtonCell`s as data cells.

Oh, and I'm building for 10.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to changing the font, you need to set the control size of the cell.

```
NSCell *theCell = ...;
[theCell setFont:[NSFont systemFontOfSize:[NSFont systemFontSizeForControlSize:NSMiniControlSize]]];
[theCell setControlSize:NSMiniControlSize];
```

Answer (score 0):

Apple is now providing an [official guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/Articles/ManipulateCellControl.html) for this.

Here's copied code snippet.

```
float fontSize = [NSFont systemFontSizeForControlSize:NSMiniControlSize];
NSCell *theCell = [theControl cell];
NSFont *theFont = [NSFont fontWithName:[[theCell font] fontName] size:fontSize];
[theCell setFont:theFont];

[theCell setControlSize:NSMiniControlSize];

[theControl sizeToFit];
```